# Drive API v3 - Getting all files inside a particular folder

Tags: python, drive

I am trying to list all files inside a folder `my-folder`.

```py
service.files().list(
q="mimeType ='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='my-folder'"
,**params)`
```

returns a dictionary like this:

```sh
{'files': [{'id': 's0meId', 'name': 'my-folder'}]}
```

Is there any method I can use to get a list of all files inside this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mimeType ='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` filter you employed filters the search to return just folders.

First get the *collection id* using your existing query.

```
 collection_id = result['files'][0]['id']
```

Then use that to formulate another query to fetch files in the collection

```
service.files().list(
    q=f"mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '{collection_id}' in parents"
    , **params)`
```